# How to use Jenkins Node Environment Variables in a Pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In the Jenkins --> Manage Jenkins --> Manage Nodes --> Configure Node, under Node Properties, you can configure Environment Variables for the Node.

Is there a way to use them in a Pipeline Script?

Now I have to do something like

```
...
environment {
    GITMIRRORS='/home/jenkins/git-mirrors'
    DLC117='/progress/117_64/dlc'
}
...
```

As a result, I'll have those paths in a lot of Pipeline scripts. But they are defined on the Node...

- Is there a way to say 'use that agent' and 'use its env variables from the main Jenkins Node configuration'?
- If not, is there way to say GITMIRRORS=GetNodeEnvVariable('...', '...')

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use them in the following ways:

```
echo"${GITMIRRORS}"
```

or you can use it in your code as:

```
gitMirrors = env.GITMIRRORS
```

Comment: Well, that's not entirely correct. It will point to the env from the master, not from the slave.

Comment: Did you try from within or outside a node block?

Answer (score 2):

[How to use Jenkins Node Environment Variables in a Pipeline script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475786/how-to-use-jenkins-node-environment-variables-in-a-pipeline-script#comment95765325_54477429)

Jenkins issue (dated back from 2017-05...)

If you can afford the change :

- move any conflicting definition of the envvar from the global setup to **all** the node setups
- or load a script or define the adequate variable value in the Jenkinsfile

references :
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44425
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44465

Comment: Thank you for sharing the issue links. It (sadly) appears that the issue of node env vars overriding global vars will not be resolved any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to do it with pure Groovy. But you can execute a command on the node and capture its output in a script block:

```
def GITMIRRORS = bat(script: "@echo %GITMIRRORS%", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

on Windows agent or

```
def GITMIRRORS = sh(script: "echo ${GITMIRRORS}", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

on Linux agent.